# Creating a Test Method for Main Method

Tags: java, testing, methods

**I am attempting to create a test method that fulfills the following requirements:**

*Create a class called Demo.java. This class will contain your main  method

Create an instance of your class by using the default constructor.

Call all your objects set methods to assign values to your object

Call the objects display method, to print out it's values

Create another instance of your class by using the parameterized  constructor

Call the objects display method, to print out it's values.*

**The following is the code I have however an error occurs in the very first line. The compiler tells me I have to rename the class named "Demo" to something else but it is required for me to name it Demo so I am not sure how to proceed from here.

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Netflix p1 = new Netflix();

p1.setPrice(11.99);

p1.setTitle("Expert");

p1.setTypeNumber(2000);

p1.display();

Netflix p2 = new Netflix(100, 7.99, "Novice");

p2.display();

}

}



public class Netflix {

private int typeNumber;

private double price;

private String title;

public Netflix() {

}

public Netflix(int typeNumber, double price, String title) {

super();

this.typeNumber = typeNumber;

this.price = price;

this.title = title;

}

public void display() {

System.out.println( "Netflix [price=" + price + ", title=" + title + ", typeNumber="

+ typeNumber + "]");

}

public String getTitle() {

return title;

}

public void setTitle(String title) {

this.title = title;

}

public int getTypeNumber() {

return typeNumber;

}

public void setTypeNumber(int typeNumber) {

this.typeNumber = typeNumber;

}

public double getPrice() {

return price;

}

public void setPrice(double price) {

this.price = price;

}

}
```

Comment: Your requirements are wrong.

Comment: What is the name of the file your code is in?

Comment: @BinaryBuilder Netflix.java

Comment: Class `Demo` should be in file `Demo.java`. Only one `public` class should be in this file (i.e. in your `Demo.java` remove `public` from `Netflix` class)

Comment: Do your requirements state that you have to have the demo class within the Netflix.java? If not I would put that in its own file or make it an inner class.

Comment: @BinaryBuilder it says that the Demo class has to contain the Netflix class so I believe my professor is asking for it to be within it. what would be an inner class?

Comment: Actually I would suggest trying what @oleg.cherednik said

Comment: If Demo class should contain Netflix class then remove public from Netflix class and change your getters and setters accordingly. That way you won't require to rename your file also. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Demo.java**

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Netflix p1 = new Netflix();
    }
}

class Netflix {
}
```

Comment: i tried this and unfortunately it gives me the same error on the first line

Comment: sorry i forgot to change the name of the file. it worked, thank you!